# How to get unique values in only ONE column in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with EMAIL and APPLICATIONS ON MS Access. First I need to filter the APPLICATION to get the values containing a specific word. (for ex. I want applications containing "apple" and it will give me applebees, applesauce, applewax, etc). 
Then I want to filter the email to only get the unique value, regardless of its application (as long as it contains the "apple").

Using UniqueValues and UniqueRecords don't work because some emails use ALL applications with the "apple".
For example:

```
firstperson@email.com --- applebees 
firstperson@email.com --- applewax 
firstperson@email.com --- applesauce 
secondperson@email.com -- applebees 
secondperson@email.com -- applesauce
```

Can anyone help me with the SQL to find the unique emails in that column?

I'd appreciate any help or guidance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
select distinct email
from t
where application like '*apple*';
```